# JWT and upgrade TLS 1.1, will there be an impact for me?

Tags: ssl, jwt

I'm logging in with JWT (Jason Web Token) on a server (Salesforce), and my client will go connect via TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.1 auth, will there be an impact for me ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question isnt very descriptive, Im not even sure what you are asking for?

Comment: There is no impact. JWT is just a format.